# Access sibling of an attribute within an object, onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, object, onclick, this, parent

I'm creating 5 `objects`, each one with a `div` attached as `source` attribute, at which `onclick` should open the relative html page in an iframe.

Need to access the simple value of `i==[i].num` for each element on `onclick function`, so to select `actor[i].num` from within `actor[i].source`, thought it should be simple.

```
// html
<div id="op0" class="op"><img src="gfx/0.svg"></div>
<div id="op1" class="op"><img src="gfx/1.svg"></div>
<div id="op2" class="op"><img src="gfx/2.svg"></div>
<div id="op3" class="op"><img src="gfx/3.svg"></div>
<div id="op4" class="op"><img src="gfx/4.svg"></div>

// js
var i=0;
let actor = {};
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        actor[i] = {
            num: i,
            source: document.getElementById('op'+[i]),
            clicked: 0 
        }
        actor[i].source.addEventListener( 'click', function() { 
            console.log(this) // the source attribute <div>
            console.log(this.num) // undefined
            console.log(parent.num) // undefined
            console.log(actor[i].num) // TypeError
            clickActor(i) // returns 5 at the time of click
        });
}

function clickActor(num){
    if (actor[num].open == 0){
        actor[num].source.classList.add("scaleUp");
        document.getElementById("iFrame").src = "op"+num+".html";
        actor[num].open = 1;
        // div to move and scale
    } else {
        actor[num].source.classList.remove("scaleUp");
        document.getElementById("iFrame").src = "";
        document.getElementById("iFrame").style.pointerEvents = "none";
        actor[num].open = 0;
        // div to move and scale back
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to add a click handler to an object property, not an element: `actor[i].source.addEventListener...`

Comment: @Katie.Sun That object property is an element, `source: document.getElmentById('op'+i)`

Answer (score 1):

`var` variables are function scopes, so your `i` variable is being reused over and over again in your loop, so that when you actually click the button, `i` will be the last number of the loop. You can bypass this by simply creating a new function scope by inserting a self-executing function in place of your callback function.

```
actor[i].source.addEventListener( 'click', (function(i) {
  return (function() { 
    console.log(actor[i].num) // this is should print out the object assign above it
    clickActor(i) // i is now the index of the actor
  });
})(i));
```

Comment: Returning the callback function at the time of execution! Of course. thanks!